# Symfony and composer component folder

Tags: jquery, symfony, composer-php

config.yml

```
jquery:
         inputs:
              - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "components/jqueryui" : "dev-master",
    "components/jquery":  "dev-master"
},
//...
```

Jquery located in vendor\composer but symfony dont reconzie this path:

> [message] The source file
>   "F:\UniServerZ\www\app/../vendor/jquery/jquery/jquery.min.js" does not
>   exist.

How i can link to components/ folder?....

Comment: I would suggest that you keep jQuery out of framework's vendors. Why do you need it there? It's a .js file, it's not namespaced, and should instead be imported through `cdn`.

Comment: I want have a always actual JQuery.

Comment: Are you sure your config.yml is tje same as posted here?

Comment: Sure, symfony just escape "components" folder...

Comment: @user3468055: well, you can, I just have to warn you that use of `dev-master` is bad practice, because if you're building large system, you have to be specific about your dependencies. What if you're system is 2 years old, and next jQuery release marks as deprecated or excludes some functions you've used in your code? And I'm sure your code does not work because it fails to autoload jQuery due to lack of namespace.

Comment: I know, i would change this when i done production procces, first for all i want to clap all app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right, I think thats because jQuery should be in public folder, `web`, so you than can access it from the outside.

composer.json:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/components"
},
```

Than you can use it like (`assetic`):

```
{% javascripts 'components/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also had to do `composer require robloach/component-installer` to add this installer into the `.json`. This installer is the one that was able to interpret the `component-dir` configuration. Without this, composer installed the `components` in the root instead of the `web` directory. More info at https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer